# JS gets automatically removed from CMS page

Tags: magento2, javascript, cms

I am trying to add some JS to the CMS homepage.
I tried to add an external js file as well as adding the code directly. See code below.
When I save the CMS page and test everything the js works fine.

However,when I reload the CMS in the Backend again to add more content the js script apparently isn't loaded from the db therefore the whole `<script>` section gets removed from the cms page and when I save it again is removed from the page.

How do I solve this?

Code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
require([
    'jquery',
    'slick'
], function ($) {
    jQuery(document).ready(function () {
        jQuery('.slider').slick();
    });
});
</script>
```

and with external file:

```
<script type="text/x-magento-init">
{
  "*": {
    "Magento_Theme/js/slider": {}
  }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

In the CMS Page, you can use try the below way.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    <![CDATA[//
        require([
            'jquery',
            'slick'
        ], function ($) {
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $('.slider').slick();
            });
        });
    //]]>
</script>
```

Hope this will work for you.

Comment: unfortunately it doesn't 
The code still gets removed completely